# C# UDP Packet Repeater: Restart will not work

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, error-handling

Long story short: I need a UDP Packet Repeater/Resender.
What should it do?
Well, it should listen for incomming packets, on specific ports and send them back yet on specified ports.
The program has a GUI with one button for running and closing the program.

The program worked fine, untill I started to... well screw with it.

Slowly I've managed to get most of the bugs out. Except for one... or more:

[c# udp socket communication - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879102/c-sharp-udp-socket-communication-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protoc)

The problem is that if I want to restart the program, by clicking the button I've get the same error in the link above.

I've tried to implement Shutdown(), Dispose(), Disconnect(), UDP_Client = null and maybe more that I've googeled but either it generated an new error, or had no effect.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace Packet_Repeater
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public bool connection_status = false;
        UdpClient[]     UDP_Client;
        IPEndPoint[]    IP_End_Point;
        IPAddress[][]   IP_Address;
        Thread[]        Task;
        public int[] upd_client_src_port, udp_client_dst_port;
        public bool[] packet_rxd;
        public bool[] task_running;
        public byte[][] BUFFER;
        public int[,] UDP_Client_num;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init_Size(int num)
    {
        UDP_Client              = new UdpClient[num];
        IP_End_Point            = new IPEndPoint[num];
        IP_Address              = new IPAddress[num][];
        Task                    = new Thread[num];
        upd_client_src_port     = new int[num];
        udp_client_dst_port     = new int[num];
        packet_rxd              = new bool[num];
        BUFFER                  = new byte[num][];
        UDP_Client_num          = new int[num,2];
        task_running            = new bool[num];
    }

    public void UDP_Init(int client_num, string target_ip, int src_port, int dst_port)
    {
        upd_client_src_port[client_num] = src_port;
        udp_client_dst_port[client_num] = dst_port;

        BUFFER[client_num] = new byte[1536];

        if(target_ip == "Any")
        {
            IP_End_Point[client_num] = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, udp_client_dst_port[client_num]);
        }
        else
        {
            IP_Address[client_num] = Dns.GetHostAddresses(target_ip);
            IP_End_Point[client_num] = new IPEndPoint(IP_Address[client_num][0], udp_client_dst_port[client_num]);
        }
        UDP_Client[client_num] = new UdpClient(upd_client_src_port[client_num]);
        UDP_Client[client_num].Client.SendTimeout       =   500;
        UDP_Client[client_num].Client.ReceiveTimeout    =   500;
    }

    public void Run_Client(int listner_client_num, int destination_client_num)
    {
        task_running[listner_client_num] = true;
        while (connection_status)
        {
            try
            {
                BUFFER[listner_client_num] = UDP_Client[listner_client_num].Receive(ref IP_End_Point[listner_client_num]);
                UDP_Client[destination_client_num].Send(BUFFER[listner_client_num], BUFFER[listner_client_num].Length, IP_End_Point[destination_client_num]);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
        Array.Clear(BUFFER[listner_client_num], 0, BUFFER[listner_client_num].Length);
// Thread.Sleep(10000);
        UDP_Client[listner_client_num].Close();
        task_running[listner_client_num] = false;
    }

    public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int number_of_connections = 2;

        if(!connection_status)
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
            connection_status = true;

            Init_Size(number_of_connections);

            UDP_Client_num[0, 0] = 0;
            UDP_Client_num[0, 1] = 1;
            UDP_Client_num[1, 0] = 1;
            UDP_Client_num[1, 1] = 0;

            UDP_Init(0, "Any", 9700, 9701);
            UDP_Init(1, "Any", 9600, 9601);
// the Problem is in this for() cycle
            for (UInt32 i = 0; i < (number_of_connections-1); i++)
            {
                Task[i] = new Thread(ThreadStart => Run_Client(UDP_Client_num[i, 0], UDP_Client_num[i, 1]));
                Task[i].Start();
            }
/*   This works OK:
myTask[0] = new Thread(ThreadStart => Run_Client(UDP_Client_num[0, 0], UDP_Client_num[0, 1]));
                myTask[0].Start();

                myTask[1] = new Thread(ThreadStart => Run_Client(UDP_Client_num[1, 0], UDP_Client_num[1, 1]));
                myTask[1].Start();
*/



      button.Text = "Close";
            button.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            connection_status = false;
            button.Enabled = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < (number_of_connections-1);)
            {
                if(!task_running[i])
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            button.Text = "Run";
            button.Enabled = true;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm on the rigth track, basicly my UDP Client does not Close properly, right?

Another strange bug that I've noticed was after the while loop in the Run_Client function. The Sleep() command did not run. It seemd to skip that part. How can this happen?

Can someone please tell me where I've screwed up?

UPDATE:
I've been still searching for the bug in the system, and found this:
While browsing I've found this usefull command on command prompt:

```
netstat -a -b -n- p udp -o
```

This helped me to find out, that endeed one of the Clinets did not close at all.
So I've added a write to textbox function at the beggining, and at the end of Run_Client().
For some reason one Task[] will not start. So this turned out to bee a Thread problem, and not a NetSocket.

Comment: See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekd1t784(v=vs.110).aspx.  A connection has 3 items.  1) Source IP. 2) Destination IP.  3) Port number.  You can't have more than one connection with all three items the same.  That is creating the error.   With multicast listener, see your link, You make a virtual connection to and end point on your PC which is called IPAddressAny.  Only one  application on a PC can make a connect to IPAnyAddress with the same Port number.  With multicast you don't need a full connection because it is a broadcast type message.  Instead you join a group.

Comment: So you say that I'm on the rigth track? The problem is that my program trys to recreate a UDP Client with the same IP/Port configuration, as before. That was not my intention. I wanted to close all UDP clients, and release all ports when closing the application by clicking on the button for the second time. By clicking on the button for the third time it should have recreate all UDP clients with the previously released IPs/Ports without a problem. That is what I wanted to do.

Comment: Some place in the code you  are trying to open a connection that is already open.  Either you are opening the same client twice when you should be opening a new connection, or you didn't close the connection properly.  if you have two udp clients listening to the same port number (broadcast), then you must use the join group.

Comment: The problem is definitely the unclosed client.
I've used this cmd netstat -a -b -n -p udp -o and saw that port 9700 stays opened. So one Close() is beeing skipped or fails.

Comment: I can't find it, you have to.  Add some debug statements to code to find out the root cause.

Comment: Frankly, using the term "connection" in the context of UDP programming is just plain a bad idea. Yes, the API permits a sort of "connect" operation, but UDP itself is connectionless and introducing the concept of a connection it just going to lead you to a highly misleading mental model of what's going on. As far as the question itself goes, there are lots of ways to screw up network programming. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, a good, direct answer is unlikely to be forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem and the solution was quite simple. For some reason there was a Threading problem in this line here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (number_of_connections); i++)
{
  Task[i] = new Thread(ThreadStart => Run_Client(UDP_Client_num[i, 0], UDP_Client_num[i, 1]));
  Task[i].Start();
  while(!task_running[i])// <<-- This is probably a better Solution
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }
  // Thread.Sleep(100);   // <<-- This Solved the Problem
}
```

For me not understood reasons, sometimes, not allways, Task[0] in the for() cycle got overwritten by Task[1]. So Task[0] never started, instead two Task[1]-s were running. Before this for() cycle, the UDP listners/clients were already initialized, so the ports were opened/occupied by the program. But because Task[0] was not running at all, it's client would not be closed when I pushed the close button on the GUI. Therefore when I pushed the button again, to restart the application, the error message popped up, cause the port specified in the code was still in use.

As jdweng recommended I've added some debug statements to the program, that did helped alot to find the source of the error. Another usefull tool was this command in command prompt:

```
netstat -a -n -p udp -o
```

This displayed me all the udp port in use.

The solution was to set the main thread to sleep for some time in the for() cycle. I've set it to 100ms, but maybee less would be ok as well. (Haven't tried it.)

Comment: Thread.Sleep should never be used to fix a threading problem, the required time to sleep is never guaranteed. Instead of using threads, consider using tasks in conjunction with the async / await keywords, and investigate **why** the delay fixed the problem, rather than patching over it.

Comment: I've put the Thread.Sleep in a while() loop, that checkes if the Task[i] is already running or not. If it's not running tha main() code will wait(go to sleep for 1ms) again and again untill the Task[i] is running.
Is this a better way to do it?

Comment: You could just use a mutex / semaphore / signalling mechanism here to communicate whether the task has started.